# ReduxForm reset form after successful "on-submit"

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to reset my form after successful submission, I tried 'reset' dispatch as mentioned in reduxForm guidelines but not getting any luck with it, the problem is I am not getting the point where to add 'reset' in my form below is my code block :

```
import React from 'react';
import DCTLeft from './DctLeft'
import DCTRight from './DctRight';
import DCTForm from './dctForm';
import { sendNewMessage } from '../../actions/messages';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {reset} from 'redux-form';

class DCT extends React.PureComponent {
    handleSubmit = (value) => {
        this.props.sendNewMessage(value);
      }
render(){
    const { messages } = this.props;
    console.log(messages)
    return (
      <section className="btns">
        <section className="navLR">
          <DCTLeft/>
          <DCTRight/>
        </section>
        <section className="scroll">
          <section className="chat_show">
            {messages && messages.map((messages, index) => (
              <dl key={index}>
              <span className="username">{messages.displayName} :</span> <dd>{messages.text}</dd>
              </dl>
            ))}
          </section>
        </section>
        <DCTForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </section>

    );
}
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      sendNewMessage: (msg) => dispatch(sendNewMessage(msg)),

    }
  }
  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  messages: state.messages.list,
  counter: state.counter.counter
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (DCT);
```

Thanks in advance :)

below is my code for my DCTForm :

```
const DCTForm = ({ handleSubmit, onSubmit }) => (
  <section className="chat-bg">
    <form className="chatBoxForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}  >
      <section className="input_container">
        <Input
          name="message"
          type="text"
        />
        <img src={Arrow_up} className="icon-static input_img" alt="Arrow_up" />
        <img src={Paper_plane} className="icon-static input_img_2" alt="Paper_plane" />
      </section>
    </form>
  </section>
);

DCTForm.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func
};

DCTForm.defaultProps = {
  handleSubmit: noop,
  onSubmit: noop
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "DCTForm"
})(DCTForm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They inject in your component props the `reset` function, this function reset the values of all fields. You can check [here](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/props.md/#-code-reset-function-code-)

Instead of import from redux-form, get it from the component props

Comment: The reset function will be here `const DCTForm = ({ handleSubmit, onSubmit, reset }) => (`

Comment: can you please give me a proper code block for it as I am not able to place it right

Comment: Just add a button using the reset function, `<button type="button" onClick={this.props.reset}>Reset</button>` you can see here: https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/ydrOKX

Comment: You can call it in any other moment you wish. If you want to reset it in any other file or moment, you can import the reset as you were doing before, and dispatch it.

import {reset} from 'redux-form';

dispatch(reset("DCTForm"))

Comment: well thanks for your help but later I found out I need to add this code at my saga.